# Modifing association in has-many through based on nested object existance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been struggling with the best way to tackle an issue for awhile now.
I have a has-many through model where Lists contain many Words, Words can be in many lists.
The association table is Lists_word.

I'm using a accepts_nested_attributes_for: Words

the words are submitted via the lists controller as nested attributes.

The logic I wanted to implement however is:

- If a user modifies a word I don't want that word to change in all
  other lists referencing that word.
- If a user modifies a word and it's a new word, then create a word and associate it to the users list.
- if a user modifies a word and it exists then change the association.
- if a user adds a word, and word already exists then just add the
  association.
- if a user adds a word and it doesn’t exist add the word
  to the collection.

To accomplish this I wrote a create_or_associate module in the Lists model. This works, however I have a strong feeling that there is a better way.

```
def create_or_associate
# For each word submitted
self.words.each do |the_list|
  if the_list.word_changed? #(New and Changed)

    if the_list.id.nil? #new list word
      if Word.exists?(word: the_list.word)
        self.words << Word.where(word: the_list.word)
      else
        #new list word not in DB
        self.words << the_list
      end
    else
      # a changed list word
      if Word.exists?(word: the_list.word)
        # changed word already in DB
        self.words << Word.where(word: the_list.word)
        self.words.find(the_list.id).delete
      else
        #changed word not in DB
        new_word=Word.create(word: the_list.word)
        self.words << new_word
        self.words.find(the_list.id).delete
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

I've not seen any similar code in my travels, which rings alarm bells that perhaps I'm not on the right track.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use this approach

```
words = params[:some_word_list]
@list = List.new  #  List.find()  if you're updating
@list.words = [] if @list.persisted?
words.each do |w|
  word = Word.find_or_create_by(:word => w)
  @list.words << word
end
@list.save
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much. So basically re-create the association each time.